# Wireframe display of terrain in ArcGlobe?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, 3d-analyst, terrain, arcglobe

I have successfully imported a terrain dataset into ArcGlobe which provides elevation values to the globe surface.

Is there an easy way I can now change the symbology/display of the terrain/globe surface to a 'wireframe' style display, ideally with customisable grid spacing etc? Or would I need to drape a grid image over the terrain surface?

Comment: I think that you'll need to use a vector grid (see createFishnet) with the height defined by your terrain dataset. Or you can use a TIN.

Comment: Executing: CreateFishnet ..._Terrain.gdb\Terrain\Terrain_Fishnet "343550 648950" "343550 648960" 50 50 # # "354350 663150" NO_LABELS "343550 648950 354350 663150" POLYLINE
Start Time: Tue Jun 17 11:44:36 2014
ERROR 000206: Cannot create FeatureClass ..._Terrain.gdb\Terrain\Terrain_Fishnet
Failed to execute (CreateFishnet).
Failed at Tue Jun 17 11:44:36 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0.13 seconds)

Comment: This is the error I get when trying to create a fishnet - though from the help it does look useful! How can I change the display in ArcGlobe to show this once I get it to work? Right now my terrain is just picking up the imagery in ArcGlobe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @radouxju I think the way to do this is by using the [**Create Fishnet (Data Management)**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002q000000) tool to create your fishnet feature class.

From the error message in your Comment it looks like you have tried to create this inside of your terrain dataset whereas I think you will have more success creating it as standalone in the file geodatabase.

Once you have the fishnet feature class you should be able to drape it over your terrain like you would any other layer.